# WP Large Images crash page

Tags: images

I am experiencing an issue where multiple 7MB image with 4000px on widest side in a photo gallery crashes a wordpress page -- or the page becomes non-respondant.

I use smush to size my images.

any ideas other than smaller images? or less images?

Comment: don't use smush or don't use such a big images.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a gallery plugin that will show thumbnail images and then load the large image after the thumbnail is clicked.
I've seen [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) one used.

Also, in most cases, 4000px images are not needed if your goal is only to let people see your photography. 1200px wide is plenty large enough.
I would also suggest making them .jpg images and compressing them to about 70% in photoshop, instead of using smush - if quality is a concern.

Downloading 14+ MB of files just to show the webpage is a very expensive process.